# Accessing SQL CE from WP7 Mango error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I'm running through the sql access example on the MSDN website (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=VS.92).aspx) and i can't understand why the following code isn't working.

MSDN Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876(v=VS.92).aspx

My Code: http://pastebin.com/MxWtGvPw

The Error: The type or namespace name 'ObservableCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm really struggling to get my head around this so if anyone has any pointers, that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

Comment: if only there was a way to hide these sort of questions, i was looking at that code for 2 hours!!! think it's time for a break! thanks!

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio you can put the cursor on the type that is giving that error and hit CTRL+PERIOD.  If you have the proper assembly in your References, a list will pop up with the namespaces you may need to include.  Not sure if applies to express versions though.

Comment: just checked and it does indeed work with express version. thanks for the tip!

Comment: @John Allers: best tip I've seen in a long time. Sure beats searching through documentation or the Object Browser!